# Profile is disabled OR it is not configured

Tags: profile, civihr

I made the mistake of messing with an extension today, and now if I go to "search" for a contact using advanced search or find contacts, i receive this error: Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
The requested Profile (gid=24) is disabled OR it is not configured to be used for 'Profile' listings in its Settings OR there is no Profile with that ID OR you do not have permission to access this profile. Please contact the site administrator if you need assistance.

I have no idea what I would have done that would have triggered this error.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: As a followup, I searched for gid=24 in the data tables.  Under Directory:Directory:URL it says the following: civicrm/profile?reset=1&gid=24&force=1

Comment: What was the extension and what did your "messing" consist of? Which CiviCRM version?

Comment: The problem arose after I installed a portion of CiviHR.  After realizing that it was renaming fields during the installation of the different modules, I stopped, and uninstalled each extension.

Answer (score 1):

The gid is the ID number of the profile.  Something is calling for that profile, but it can't/won't pull it up for one of those various reasons.

Two factors to consider:

1. What is profile 24?
2. Why is Advanced Search trying to use it?

My hunch is that CiviHR creates a special profile and sets it to be used as the default search view.  You can customize the columns you see when you run a search, and to do it, you set up a profile with the fields you want.

First, go into your profiles administration page and look for the one with ID 24 (looking both in the User-Defined Profiles and the Reserved Profiles).  If there is none, that explains why it can't be found.  If you find it, click Settings and check all the "used for" boxes.  See if that helps.

Next, check your search preferences (Administer - Customize Data and Screens - Search Preferences) and see if a Default Contact Search Profile is set.  Set it to None and save.

Answer (score 0):

Running WordPress CiviCRM version 4.7.7

*May I suggest you post the traceback for the CiviCRM error?*

I am getting the **same error**, but I do not agree with the assumption that gid is referring to the profiles on **Administer/Custom Data and Screens/Profile**. There are actually two profiles (groups) in CiviCRM. This one refers to the **civicrm_group** table, but there is another one in **civicrm_uf_group**. In the website I am administering the ids and names in both groups look almost identical, but civicrm_uf_group is missing gid=14 and the other table is not.

**So where do you Administer the civicrm_uf_group in the CiviCRM user interface? I cannot find any constraints between the 2 tables. I checked all civicrm_uf_* tables and they do not reference gid=14, so where is it coming from? Even knowing which page or menu item is causing this error would be helpful.**

See the following CiviCRM log:

> May 29 15:06:44  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
>   (
>      [message] => The requested Profile (gid=14) is disabled OR it is not > > configured to be used for 'Profile' listings in its Settings OR there is no Profile with that ID OR you do not have permission to access this profile. Please contact the site administrator if you need assistance.
>      [code] => 
>   )
>
> May 29 15:06:44  [info] $backTrace = #0 /../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(371): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
>
> 1. /../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/UFGroup.php(368): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("The requested Profile (gid=14) is disabled OR it is not configured to be used...")
> 2. /../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/UFGroup.php(217): CRM_Core_BAO_UFGroup::getFields("14", FALSE, 2, 5, FALSE, FALSE, "Profile", 5, NULL, 5)
> 3. /../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Profile/Page/Listings.php(143): CRM_Core_BAO_UFGroup::getListingFields(2, 5, FALSE, "14", FALSE, "Profile", 5)
> 4. /../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Profile/Page/Listings.php(288): CRM_Profile_Page_Listings->preProcess()
> 5. /../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Profile/Page/Router.php(124): CRM_Profile_Page_Listings->run()
> 6. /../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(312): CRM_Profile_Page_Router->run((Array:2), NULL)
> 7. /../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
> 8. /../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:2))
> 9. /../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1227): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:2))
>      10.internal function: CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke(Object(WP))
> 10. /../wp-includes/plugin.php(601): call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:1))
> 11. /../wp-includes/class-wp.php(737): do_action_ref_array("wp", (Array:1))
> 12. /../wp-includes/functions.php(952): WP->main("")
> 13. /../wp-blog-header.php(16): wp()
> 14. /../index.php(17): require("/var/www/vhosts/casem-acmse.org/httpdocs/wp-blog-header.php")
> 15. {main}

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you would be better posting this as a new question, but here goes (since I can't answer your answer with an answer! or maybe only a hint - civicrm_uf_group table holds the name of the profile (group of fields), what the fields in the profile are used for etc. You administer these via Admin > Customise > Profiles.