# How can I display the participations of events in the user profile?

Tags: civievent, profile, joomla, user

How can I display on Joomla 3.6.4 with CiviCRM 4.7.13 the tickets purchased by a user on his user profile?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried the default contact dashboard provided by CiviCRM? At least in Drupal the URL would be yoursite.org/civicrm/user?reset=1

Contacts can do many things (such as renewing a membership or printing an invoice) from the dashboard, you can edit what contacts are able to see here: yoursite.org/civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/display?reset=1
(above the choice for the WYSIWYG editor).

Make sure users have the correct permissions described here: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/initial-set-up/permissions-and-access-control/#giving-users-the-ability-to-view-their-contact-dashboard

Comment: Please I need some more help.
I still get the error:

The requested Profile (gid=15) is disabled OR it is not configured to be used for 'Profile' listings in its Settings OR there is no Profile with that ID OR you do not have permission to access this profile. 

I already added users, groups, added the user into groups, added roles, assigned groups to the roles, and added several ACL in CiviCRM. Still I cant access the users profile.

Comment: I also edited the Joomla ACL to give registered users the permission to see the "access Contact Dashboard ", but still, same error

Comment: When do you get the error? As soon as you try accessing the dashboard or later? Please have a look at those links as well and see if the solutions there may help you:

https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=27333.0

https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4449/profile-is-disabled-or-it-is-not-configured

Comment: Yes, I get that after I login on the frontend and the click on "my profile".
I updated the setting now for public to allow all for profiles. Still, same error.
I must be missing something bigger.
Is there anywhere an example of the minimum of ACL you need to create in CiviCRM per default to make that work?

Comment: I am usually not working with joomla but maybe you are trying to access the wrong page. I was talking about the dashboard, not a profile. Please have a look at the joomla demo here: http://joomla.demo.civicrm.org/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/user&reset=1 (login with demo|demo) - this is the dashboard and the url that should bring it up. If that does not help I think someone with more joomla skills would need to help...

Comment: You are the best !!! Thank you!!!
So the solution is: to enable that users can see their profile, in Joomla the menu link must be set to: CiviCRM Dashboard, not to "Profile View Page"

all works like a charm!!!